# Saving Streaming Data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to save some data into SQL Server from a C# console application using twitter streaming api. I have tried to save the data in normal saving but it didn't worked. Can anyone please suggest which way should I use to store streaming data?

Here is my C# code. Thank you in advance

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials("xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx");
        Stream_FilteredStreamExample();
    }

    private static void Stream_FilteredStreamExample()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=Surveillance;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();

        var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
        stream.AddTrack("ebola");

        stream.MatchingTweetAndLocationReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!args.Tweet.IsRetweet)
            {
                var tweet = args.Tweet;
                if(args.Tweet.Coordinates!=null)
                {
                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TwitterDatabase(Tweet,Latitude,Longitude) values('"+tweet.Text+"','"+tweet.Coordinates.Latitude+"','"+tweet.Coordinates.Longitude+"')",conn);
                    Console.WriteLine("tweets:{0}", tweet.Text);
                    Console.WriteLine("(Coardinates{0}, {1})", tweet.Coordinates.Latitude, tweet.Coordinates.Longitude);
                 }
            }
        };

        stream.StartStreamMatchingAnyCondition();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

In Database i have datatype

```
Tweet = varchar(150)

Latitude = float

Longitude = float
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection is closed when you try to save a tweet. Open the connection and than save the tweet in your event and execute the command:

```
private static void Stream_FilteredStreamExample()
{
    var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
    stream.AddTrack("ebola");
    stream.MatchingTweetAndLocationReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (!args.Tweet.IsRetweet)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=Surveillance;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
            conn.Open();
            var tweet = args.Tweet;
            if(args.Tweet.Coordinates!=null)
            {
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TwitterDatabase(Tweet,Latitude,Longitude) values '"+tweet.Text+"','"+tweet.Coordinates.Latitude+"','"+tweet.Coordinates.Longitude+"')",conn))
                {
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
             }
             }
        }
    };
  stream.StartStreamMatchingAnyCondition();
}
```

You realy have to look at parameterized queries. You are now exposed to sql injecting.

Answer (score 1):

The data i am trying to store is an structured data so for storing into database the below code worked for me.

```
stream.MatchingTweetAndLocationReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!args.Tweet.IsRetweet)
            {
                using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-PAL1Q8DR163\AVINASH;Initial Catalog=Surveillance;Integrated Security=True"))
                {
                conn.Open();
                var tweet = args.Tweet;
                if (args.Tweet.Coordinates != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TwitterDatabase(Tweet,Latitude,Longitude) VALUES(@Tweeets, @LatCoordinate, @LongCoordinate)", conn))
                        {
                            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Tweeets", tweet.Text));
                            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LatCoordinate", tweet.Coordinates.Latitude));
                            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LongCoordinate", tweet.Coordinates.Longitude));
                            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }catch{
                        Console.WriteLine("Could not insert.");
                    }
                }

            }
    }

        };
    stream.StartStreamMatchingAnyCondition();

}

 }
}
```